# Regex for SimpleDateFormat string

Tags: java, regex, simpledateformat

I have dates mainly in the forms of `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`. I want to pattern match `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Is it trivial to write an regex for this purpose? I am new to regex so would appreciate any resource tat could get me up to speed?

Comment: I don't understand. What purpose does the regex have?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to find these date notations in a String, then regexes is indeed a good choice. You could use this regex:

```
\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b
```

See it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/qZOTsUikbo. Note: this matches "*dates*" like
`9999-99-99 99:99:99` as well. If that is a problem for you, you could verify them after you found the potential Strings.

If you want to parse them, then use a SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("2013-12-24 18:31:20");
```

Comment: There is no need to escape `-` if it is outside of character class `[...]`.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I always hesitate.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to write reg expression for it.

Java already has support for it. Here is the link to follow.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: WHere did OP mention android?

Comment: Meant for Java. Apologize!

Comment: Good lead, yet the link should point to java spec instead of android. Remember that they're not necessarily the same :) (although we know they don't vary that much). Happy holidays!